# How to prove that the spin operator commutes with the position operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-spin, commutator, observables

In the lecture notes on Quantum Mechanics I'm reading, the author claims that the position operator $\hat{q}$, the square spin operator $\hat{s}^2$ and the spin operator component $\hat{s}_0$ (in a spherical basis) form a complete set of commuting operators. But how do you prove that the position and spin operators commute? Especially since we know that the position and orbital angular momentum operators do not commute instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do position and spin commute?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/777773/)

Comment: Yes thank you very much!